# Does having multiple partitions on one disk parallelize writing to disk?

Tags: linux, redhat

I have a 500 Gb disk and trying to decide if dividing them into three partitions makes a difference in performance in linux. i.e if there's multiple threads writing to different partitions in same disk, - if first thread is writing to partition 1 in disk 1 , would the second thread have to wait to write to partition 2 on the same disk ?

Answer (score 4):

A disk is a physical device with a physical write head (ignoring SSDs for a moment).  It can only write to one location at a time.  Multiple threads attempting to write at the same time will contend with each other, and in fact make overall speed slower as the head has to do more seeking to the correct position. The fastest write is one long continuous right in adjacent sectors.

SSDs do not have the physical aspect, but they do have limits on their IO speed. Adding threads does not change that underlying bottleneck so won't increase the speed.

This is all assuming that a given thread is ready to write at the maximum speed.  If an application depends on some other resource (user input, network) then adding threads may make it appear to write faster as those threads are doing more work to 'queue up' data to be written to the disk.

Comment: Doesn't SSD have smart queues which would optimize your writes?

Answer (score 1):

**No. Contrary.** Common magentic hard disks are most performant when writing to areas of the disk that are close to each other. Consider the simple case where two large files are written, once in almost the same region of the disk, once in very distant parts. In the first case, the writing head can move practically continously, in the latter case considerable time is spent moving the head between two distant points.

Common filesystem drivers already are highly optimized for making reasonable decisions on when and where to continue writing.
Many of those optimizations are lost if you are writing concurrently to completely different regions of the disk, employing two instances of the filesystem driver, each with their own limited view on outstanding writes.

---

Even SSDs (which do not spend more time for dealing with the physical distance) perform better when writing large areas at once (spanning only full blocks instead of making small writes here, then small writes there). You can therefore expect a single filesystems to still perform better than multiple file systems on seperate partitions would, even in the case of SSD.

---

If your idea for the partition also comes from wanting to make sure that one filesystem being full does not block writes to the others (reserving different maximum space for each folder) - there are solutions to that for single-filesystem aswell. The keyword you are looking for in that case is *quota*.

Comment: How does this tally with https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404119/632951 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13422318/632951 and https://www.quora.com/Can-a-program-read-write-at-multiple-positions-simultaneously-on-a-SSD-disk and https://archive.is/fxkr5#selection-627.183-627.377

Comment: https://archive.is/RUlZl#selection-3715.0-3785.432